# Mailman: How to split up mails into batches

Tags: email, postfix, mailman

Having huge mailinglists with maybe 10k subscribers, is there a way to split list forwarded by mailman into batches maybe a 1000 mails sending out each batch maybe with an offset? Or would it make more sense to configure postifx  a little smarter?

Answer (score 2):

The only reason you would want to split your mailing queue is to pass spam filters on major mail servers, but the problem is it won't help you to get through them. Instead of trying to bypass spam-protection by technical means, you should comply to [Bulk Senders Guidelines](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en) which [every](https://mail.live.com/mail/policies.aspx) [major](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN3435.html) [server](https://postmaster.aol.com/best-practices) has. This mean implementing [SPF](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/spf.html), [DKIM](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-dkim-with-postfix-on-debian-wheezy) and [unsubsrcibe header](http://www.list-unsubscribe.com/). That way your mail won't be sent to spam no matter how much messages you are sending in one batch...

Comment: It's not about spam -- I want to leverage load a little on my box a little. But tahnks for the hint anyway.